# How can I tell which edition of SQL Server is on a particular disc?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have several SQL Server 2008 R2 setup discs around, but they're not labeled with which edition (Standard, Developer, Enterprise etc.) they are for.

Running the setup program doesn't give much help, as it just shows that it's a SQL Server 2008 R2 install. I can't see anything more specific, unless I'm just looking in the wrong place.

How can I find out the actual edition of SQL Server that is on the disc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no different installations for different editions. It's based on the product key you enter during installation.

If you are unsure of your product key what version is, you can run the installation up to the point where you enter key, see Licence Terms for specific edition in the next step, and just Cancel from there.